# How to pass argument to std::bind to a function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code which used std::bind :

```
 EventListenerCustom* _createNewObjectlistener = 
eventDispatcher->addCustomEventListener(Constants::MY_EVENT, 
std::bind(&MyClass::MyFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

It seems I create many different kinds of object listeners, where the only difference is the event, and the function being called. If I wanted to encapsulate the above code into a function:

- How would I pass MyClass::MyFunction as an argument to the function ?
- What would the function signature and parameters look like ?

I imagine the function would look something like this:

```
EventListenerCustom* MyFunc(<What Goes Here> functionToBeBound,<What goes here> object,std::string EVENT){
    EventListenerCustom* eventListener = eventDispatcher->addCustomEventListener(EVENT, std::bind(functionToBeBound, object, std::placeholders::_1));
    return eventListener;
}
```

What should the function look like ? And How do I call it? What would the calling code look like?

EDIT: Concrete details:

I have many listener objects which are created in identical ways:

```
auto eventDispatcher = _dragNode->getEventDispatcher();

_createNewObjectlistener = eventDispatcher->addCustomEventListener(Constants::MY_EVENT, std::bind(&MyClass::myOtherFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1));

_moveNewObjectlistener = eventDispatcher->addCustomEventListener(Constants::MY_EVENT2 std::bind(&MyClass::myFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Constants::MY_EVENT etc are just const char* .

The only difference is the Function being called, and the string constant used as an event name. How can I encapsulate this into a function ? I have tried John Zwinck's solution below, but for some reason I can't get it to compile because the compiler complains:

```
: No viable conversion from '__bind<void (*&)(cocos2d::EventCustom *), MyNameSpace::MyClass *, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> &>' to 'const std::function<void (EventCustom *)>'
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it simpler, create a typedef for a pointer to any member function in `MyClass` which has the appropriate signature:

```
typedef void (MyClass::*MyMemberFn)(int); // replace int and void as needed
```

Then:

```
EventListenerCustom* MyFunc(MyMemberFn functionToBeBound, MyClass* object, std::string EVENT){
    return eventDispatcher->addCustomEventListener(EVENT, std::bind(functionToBeBound, object, std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

Comment: But won't this make it non-reusable, since I can only use the function that has been defined in the typedef? What if I want to pass other functions in some other class ?

Comment: @KaizerSozay: That typedef is called MyMemberFn and does not refer to any particular member function, that is to say it is compatible with any member function in MyClass which takes an `int` (or whatever the single parameter is that you have), and returns `void` (or whatever your actual functions return, so long as they are all alike in signature).

Comment: Is there any documentation I can read to better understand this specific usage of typedef ? The syntax seems weird to me.

Comment: It doesn't recognise my class name, even though I have placed the typedef statement directly above my class definition. It says "Use of undeclared identifier 'MyClass'.

Comment: If you remove 'MyClass' from the typedef, then there is an error :  No viable conversion from '__bind<void (*&)(MyFunctionParamenter *), MyNamespace::MyClass *, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> &>' to 'const std::function<void (MyFunctionParameter *)>'

Comment: You need to put the typedef *after* the declaration of MyClass.  That's why it's telling you "Use of undeclared identifier MyClass."  If you need to, add a "forward declaration" by saying `class MyClass` at the top, in the same scope as MyClass.

Answer (score 0):

What you're really looking for is `std::function`.  The documentation for such is here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Their example is *really good* at explaining how it's used, but for your case (or related) try this:

```
std::function<void(int)> func1 = std::bind(MyClass::MyFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

What this will do is create an object which can be called, and the first argument is forwarded on to the first argument of the member function, both of which should be `int` type, and it returns nothing.  You don't actually need address-of operator for the function name.

The cool part here is that the object returned by `std::bind` can be passed into the constructor of `std::function` and all its information is preserved.  So when you need a concrete type that can be copied and all that cool stuff (passed into a function NOT by reference for example) then use a `std::function` as it will do the job, as long as it's not trying to copy a non-copyable type or something.  `std::function` can also be initialized with a function pointer.  It's generally just "better" than function pointers for C++, especially combined with `std::bind` to handle classes.

I could write out more examples, but check out the link above, and check out `std::bind` on that same website.  Both should help.