# How to pass function pointer to bind?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code:

```
_createNewObjectlistener = eventDispatcher->addCustomEventListener(Constants::EVENT_CREATE_OBJECT, std::bind(&ObjectPlacementManager::receiveCreateObjectEvent, this, std::placeholders::_1));
_eventListeners.insert(_createNewObjectlistener);

_moveNewObjectlistener = eventDispatcher->addCustomEventListener(Constants::EVENT_MOVE_NEW_OBJECT, std::bind(&ObjectPlacementManager::receiveMoveCurrentGameObjectEvent, this, std::placeholders::_1));
_eventListeners.insert(_moveNewObjectlistener);

.... many more listeners created
```

Since the only difference between the creation code for each listener, is the `Constant::EVENT_NAME` and the function being called, I am trying to encapsulate it into a function.

The result of `bind` must be of type const `std::function<void(EventCustom*)>&`

The functions like `ObjectPlacementManager::receiveMoveCurrentGameObjectEvent` all have the same signature:

```
void receiveMoveCurrentGameObjectEvent(EventCustom* event){
 ....
}
```

I have tried: [How to pass argument to std::bind to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55769865/how-to-pass-argument-to-stdbind-to-a-function)

```
typedef void (*callback_function)(EventCustom*);

EventListenerCustom* createCustomListener(callback_function func, std::string EVENT){
    auto eventDispatcher = _dragNode->getEventDispatcher();
    auto listener = eventDispatcher->addCustomEventListener(EVENT, std::bind(&func, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    _eventListeners.insert(_createNewObjectlistener);
    return listener;
}
```

But the error I get is:

```
No viable conversion from '__bind<void (**)(cocos2d::EventCustom *), bejoi::ObjectPlacementManager *, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> &>' to 'const std::function<void (EventCustom *)>'
```

I have also tried making a function:

```
EventListenerCustom* createCustomListener(void* func, std::string EVENT){
    auto eventDispatcher = _dragNode->getEventDispatcher();
    auto listener = eventDispatcher->addCustomEventListener(EVENT, std::bind(func, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    return listener;
}
```

But the error I get is:

```
No viable conversion from '__bind<void *&, mynamespace:: ObjectPlacementManager *, const std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> &>' to 'const std::function<void (EventCustom *)>'
```

Comment: `But the error I get is: 'No viable conversion' from....`. Could you paste the full error message?

Comment: @Kerndog73 updated the body of my question.

Comment: As always in these cases: why `std::bind` and its crazy rules? Just use a lambda.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I don't know very much about C++ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is because you're taking the address of a function pointer. So you're passing a pointer to a pointer to a function to `std::bind`.

The second error is because you used a `void *` and somehow expected that to work!

Try this MCVE:

```
struct Event {};

struct Dispatcher {
  void addListener(int, const std::function<void(Event *)> &) {}
};

struct Manager {
  void receive(Event *) {}

  void addListener(int type, void (Manager::*receiver)(Event *)) {
    dis.addListener(type, std::bind(receiver, this, std::placeholders::_1));
  }

  void test() {
    addListener(42, &Manager::receive);
  }

  Dispatcher dis;
};
```

Comment: @KaizerSozay You can just write `addListener(42, &Manager::receive);`. You don't have to call `std::bind` every time. I was just showing the difference between the two in the `test` function.

Comment: But then why are you calling dis.addListener before that ?