# How to encapsulate function binding?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have:

```
std::function<void(EventCustom*)> f = std::bind( &MyClass::MyFunc, myObj, _1 );
```

The above line is used throughout my code, but instead of MyClass, it may be MyClass2, MyClass3, myObj3,myObj2 etc used in place of MyClass and myObj

Is there some way I can wrap the above in a function ? The problem I am having is, unless I use the code exactly as written above, the output of bind does not exactly create an std::function, so the compiler complains.

EventCustom* is an object used in the cocos2d-x library. So if you download and build a cocos2d-x project you can use it.

Comment: It's entirely clear to me what you're asking... 
Could you upload a minimal example where you attempted to wrap this code in a function and got compiler warnings/ errors?

Comment: @OrGroman The problem I was trying to solve I described in more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55770302/how-to-pass-function-pointer-to-bind . Found an answer too.

Answer (score 1):

What about lambda?

```
std::function<void(EventCustom*)> f = [&myObj2](EventCustom* pEvent) {
    myObj2.MyFunc(pEvent);
};
```

Comment: but if I put the above code in a function, how do I pass the function as a parameter ? I can certainly pass the object. Anyway, I found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55770302/how-to-pass-function-pointer-to-bind